# How to alter ORC file's embedded schema?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, orc

​Is there a light-weight solution to change the datatype of specific column in ORC file without having to convert entire column datatype and re-writing entire orc file?

The following is a heavy-weight solution:

1. Read orc file in Spark
2. Convert datatype of a specific column
3. Write converted orc file to HDFS

Looking for a light-weight solution where I can just alter embedded metadata info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the answer that you're looking for, but no you can't change a column type in ORC without re-generating the file. What you're suggesting is the correct way to do it.

ORC includes indexes and aggregated values in the file header, and so changing a string -> double would require the entire column to be scanned so that the min/max/average etc could be calculated for what is now a numerical column.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Even if it were to change a TIMESTAMP column to DATE, would this be impossible?

Comment: Any type change requires a full re-processing of the file, yes.

Comment: Thanks Ben! Also, I asked Cloudera Support the same question. Got the same answer.